# javascript skip to next form field on Maxlen

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, forms

I have a form that collects telphone numbers, there are 3 fields, when a user types in the maxLen of numbers in a specific field I want to automaticaly jump to the next input field, cant seem to get it working

**HTML**

```
<!-- Other inputs above -->
  <label>Telephone Number</label>
  <input type="text" class="phone" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="checkLen(this,this.value)">
  <input type="text" class="phone" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="checkLen(this,this.value)">
  <input type="text" class="phone" size="4" maxlength="4" onkeyup="checkLen(this,this.value)">
```

asp.net backend so IDs are all dynamically generated so its hard to grab an element by ID.

**javascript**

```
function checkLen(x, y) {
    if (y.length == x.maxLength) {
        var next = x.tabIndex;
        if (next < document.getElementsByClassName("phone").length) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("phone").elements[next].focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tabIndex is always 0 isn't it, since you didn't set a tabIndex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using jQuery.

You could move it to next input instead of trying to use `tabindex`

```
$(".phone").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).next('.phone').focus();
    }
});
```

Also remove `onclick` attribute handler as you are binding it like above.